# Show/hide an image using setInterval (and where do I place the code?)

Tags: javascript, animation

I need some help on writing the appropriate JavaScript and on where to place it. What I want to do is pretty simple...

I want to hide a div when the page is first loaded and then have it display permanently after a set interval (let's call it 10 minutes). I've looked all over and from what I can tell, I need to use the setInterval or setTimeout function.

Two problems...

- I don't know JavaScript, so I'm just trying to hack this together
- I'm using WordPress and I have no idea where the script would need to be placed for this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #my_div {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- remove noscript if you don't want it displayed if JS is off -->
        <noscript>
            <style>
                #my_div {
                    display:block;
                }
            </style>
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="my_div">the hidden div</div>

        <!-- More HTML content -->

           <!-- JavaScript just before the end of the body -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function() {
                var el = document.getElementById('my_div');
                if( el ) 
                    el.style.display = 'block';
            }, 600000); // 10 minutes
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 - hey, is there a way to get dom events to work in jsfiddle - window.onload seems to be ignored

Comment: @AdamRackis: What do you have selected for the load option in the menu on the left?

Comment: I don't like this method... if for some reason the user does not have javascript enabled the div will *never* show. Hiding it on window.load will provide the same effect.

Comment: @j-man86: Well, it depends on if OP wants it to be shown without JS. In any case, I updated with a `<noscript>` tag to display it in that case. I wouldn't recomment `window.onload` because then it will display until all scripts and images are completely loaded, and then it will disappear.

Comment: Thanks (to everyone) ... I ended up using this and it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

Grab the window.onload event, hide the div immediately, then call setTimeout to show it again:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var divToHide = document.getElementById("divId");
    divToHide.style.display = "none";

    setTimeout(function() { divToHide.style.display = "block" }, 600000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not deal with showing and hiding elements once they have been loaded on to page. That is exclusively javascript's domain. So...

1. Locate your theme folder. So first check which theme is active in admin -> appearance -> themes, then go to the folder in your FTP: wp-content/themes/yourtheme
2. Locate and open header.php

add the following right before the `</head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

         var $img = getElementById('myimage');
         $img.style.display = 'none';

         function showImg() {
              $img.style.display = ''
         }

         setTimeout("showImg()",3000);
     }
</script>
```

the "3000" is the time in milliseconds that you want to delay. You also need to give your image an ID:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" id="myimage" />
```